# VBA How to run function from one module on another workbook

Tags: vba

Currently, I have two files. Test1.xlsm, Test2.xlsm

I currently have a function called Findrow written in the module of Test1.xlsm.

Findrow currently takes two arguments (String, Worksheet)

In Module1 of Test1, I want to use findRow in test2 and return the value of the row to the module of Test1.

Comment: What is preventing you from copying the module to the other workbook?

Comment: Everybody in the office already has a copy of that file so to add that module, I would have to send a new round of that file with the module included for it to work. I would rather just get it working in my file.

Comment: At the very least, you need to set a reference in Test2.xlsm to Test1.xlsm, but this will require editing Test2.xlsm.

Comment: Is the function in Test1 a UDF that you are going to use a cell formula in Test2?

Comment: Nope. The custom function I wrote takes two arguments, String and Worksheet. It goes to Test2 and activates the worksheet and returns the row that the string appears on in column A of that worksheet.

Comment: Wait, are you using Findrow from Test1 to get data in Test2 or are you trying to run Findrow from Test2 to get data from Test2?

Comment: I am using findRow from Test1 to get data in Test2 but I am using findRow in a module of Test1

Comment: I downvoted your question as it is terribly unclear as to what you are trying to accomplish. Take some time, edit the question to be more clear and I will gladly remove the downvote and try again to answer.

Comment: Done I edited it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to Findrow, you can pass in the worksheet from Test2.xlsm:

```
Findrow("SearchString", Application.Workbooks("Test2.xlsm").Worksheets("SheetName")
```

This is contingent upon both workbooks being open.